# Echo selected value drop down list PHP

Tags: php

I have a drop down list and when I select a value in it I need to print the value of the choice I made. This is the code i have so far:

```
<?php
$aPersoon = array( 10=>'Barends', 20 => 'van Hulten', 30 => 'Jansen', 40 => 'Waili', 50=> 'Ketelaars');
?>
```

Array

```
<select name="per1" id="per1">
          <option selected="selected">Kies een</option>
          <?php
            foreach($aPersoon as $key => $value):
            echo '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</option>';

            endforeach;
            ?>
        </select>
```

All the names are in the drop down list. When, I for example, click on `Jansen` I need to echo the value `30` because that's the value of `Jansen`.

Comment: Where do you need to echo the "value" ?

Comment: @Epodax under the drop down list.

Comment: @KipVerslaafde you need javascript for it.

Comment: So, you need javascript to do that, some `onClick` or `onChange` event should be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use `Javascript` for the `onChange()` event after choosing an option. So here is an example you could use for it:

Your script modified:

```
<select name="per1" id="per1" onChange="myFunction(this)">
    <option selected="selected">Kies een</option>
    <?php
    foreach($aPersoon as $key => $value):
    echo '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</option>';

    endforeach;
    ?>
</select><br />
Your option: <span id="myfunction">You haven't selected an option yet</span>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction(event) {
    var output = event.value;
    document.getElementById("myfunction").innerHTML = output;
}
</script>
```

I hope this will help you!

Comment: Im not allowed to use javascript.

Comment: There is no other option than using javascript for it then. Is there a specific reason you're not allowed to use JS?

Comment: There's no other way of showing the value unless you submit the form and echo the selected value in PHP. You would then have to tie in sessions, get the session value and output it.

In all honesty, it would be best to just argue the case for Javascript. It solves so many problems such as this if you're using it for display purposes.

Comment: Or you could post the value.

Answer (score 1):

**PHP won't work as it's a server side scripting language.**  You need to use JS for that. **JS** helps because it can handle client side events like changing drop-down menu item.

You need to use [onchange()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) event for that. It triggers the function when some one change the value from dropdown.

To use that update your HTML like this:

```
     <select name="per1" id="per1" onchange="updateBottomValue(this.value);">
      <option selected="selected">Kies een</option>
      <?php
        foreach($aPersoon as $key => $value):
        echo '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</option>';

        endforeach;
        ?>
    </select>
    <span id="selectedValue"></span>
```

Now you need to make a function which will handle the onChange event of the dropdown in JS like below:

```
function updateBottomValue(selectedvalue) {
         document.getElementById("selectedValue").innerHTML=selectedvalue;
}
```

In above function we've used [document.getElementByID](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp) which look for specific DOM element by it's ID and can perform HTML and CSS related actions. In above example we're just setting it's HTML content.